# Minecraft java.io.IOException : Unable to connect to remote host : Connection refused

Tags: games

I installed java 9.On minecraft i can play with java 9 on singleplayer.But When i want to connect to a server minecraft doesn't crash it only gives an error saying "java.io.IOException : Unable to connect to remote host : Connection refused" I looked up to internet but i couldn't find something similar to mine
I also got an error from another server.The error is Internal Exception : java.lang.runtimeException : Unable to access address of buffer.

Answer (score 0):

you have a premium account?, i got the same problem with a minecraft server and was that you need a premium account, i bought my premium account and all was solved, by the way this question is not related to elementary so pleease check this in a minecraft forum or in the suport page of [mojang](https://help.mojang.com/)

Comment: I can't find solutions to my errors >:

Answer (score 0):

Found it.It is because of Java.I uninstalled Java 9 And i installed Java 7 Everything worked fine.(I didn't install Java 8 because last time it was crashing Minecraft.)

Comment: Does Java 9 even exist  ? It is prerelease